# "watch a movie" or "watching a movie"

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

> Could I join watching a movie tonight?

or

> Could I join to watch a movie tonight?

I doubt if it is a form of a verb as noun (gerund) or reason and purpose (infinitive)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in both sentences, you are missing an _article_. You can watch _the_ movie (if it is a specific one), or you can watch _a_ movie (if you don't know or care which one it is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before *gerund* or *infinitive* comes *transitive* or *intransitive* **here!** I think *join* should be a transitive verb in this sentence and thus, first you should include a direct object.

Said that, *join **who***?

Also, I'd structure that like this...

> *May (could) I join **you** for a movie tonight?*

Answer (score 0):

You can say "to join someone in doing something".

> Can I join you in watching a movie tonight?